# call methods defined in the fragments from SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using SherlockFragmentActivity with two fragments.
I want to call methods defined in the fragments from my SherlockFragmentActivity.

```
Fragment1 extends Fragment{

  protected void resetSettings(){

     //my code 
   }     
}
```

and the activity

```
 Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    //here i want to call resetSettings()

 }
```

Comment: Does Main have reference to your Fragment1 ? If yes, just do `myMain.resetSettings();` oh, i see - it's protected. is this a visibility problem?

Comment: @Shark No its not a visibility problem. Actually i want an instance of my fragment class in activity to call its methods.

Comment: So then do just that.

Comment: @Shark how to get reference of that fragment in sherlock fragment activity

Comment: How / where do you instantiate that Fragment1 ?

Comment: @Shark [updated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656230/call-methods-of-fragment-from-sherlock-fragment-activity)